# Text Layout Framework support bullet?

Tags: actionscript-3

Does TLF editor allow user to add UL or LI tag through a bullet button in the toolbar?

Answer (score 2):

There's actually no support for bullet list in the TextLayoutFramework. You might be able to insert unicode characters and hack it around, though they will be selectable and deletable.

Half implemented features like this are becoming kind of an expected part of Adobe's offering.

Answer (score 0):

It's still brutal for sure, but check out http://forums.adobe.com/message/2105729#2105729  for some more information on how to make a something that LOOKS like a bulleted list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <TextFlow verticalAlign="inherit" lineBreak="inherit" paddingBottom="inherit" paddingLeft="inherit" paddingRight="inherit" paddingTop="inherit" whiteSpaceCollapse="preserve" xmlns=" http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008"><p marginLeft="20"><span>  </span><span fontFamily="Times New Roman" fontSize="32">  • Round bullet '\u2022'  ◦ White bullet '\u25e6'  ▪ Black small square '\u25aa'  ▫ White small square '\u25ab'  </span><span>  </span></p></TextFlow>
```